# Android studio, what is wrong with this onBackPressed() code?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I used below code to close app after back button pressed. Some time ago it worked but I tried to use it again and have:

Error:(88, 13) error: class, interface, or enum expected.

If I remove this code app can be build, I don't see where is problem?

Here is the `MainActivity` where `onBackPressed` is implemented:

```
package com.example.chab.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.e);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.f);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.g);

    Picasso.with(this).load("http:/1.jpeg").into(image);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://1.jpeg").into(image1);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://1.jpeg").into(image2);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://1.jpeg").into(image3);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://1.jpeg").into(image4);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://1.jpeg").into(image5);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://1.jpeg").into(image6);

    Button btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);
    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activitydwa.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
}  //THIS BRACKET MUST BE MOVED TO THE END OF CODE!

private Boolean exit = false;
@Override
private void super.onBackPressed() {
    if (exit) {
        this.finish(); // finish activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Solved. 
Bracket before Boollean must be moved to the end of code. Then all works. Thank you.

Comment: Other than that `onBackPressed` needs to be `public` the code seems fine. Where exactly is it located in?

Comment: There may be problem in any part; pls check the following ;Boolean is an object wrapper whereas boolean is a primitive data type; overridden methoad must be protected or public;

Comment: code it's in mainactivity, just after onCreate(). There is nothing else after. If I remove above code, not problem,

Comment: You'd get this error if you placed the code outside of your activity class on the root level of a .java file. Looks for unbalanced `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have your method implemented outside of the class. In java, methods need to belong to a `class`, `interface`, or `enum`. Double check your brackets and move your method to the inside of your class brackets. Your second problem is that you have the wrong signature for the `onBackPressed` method. See the code below:

---

This is what you have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
  }
}

private Boolean exit = false;

@Override
private void super.onBackPressed() {
  // ...
}
```

This is what you need:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
  }

  private Boolean exit = false;

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried to put it inside MainActivity class and it didn't work. I tried again and works!! Thank you everybody.

Comment: look at the code carefully; the method signature is different compared to your original codeblock

Comment: also, if this solved your problem, mark it as an accepted answer so that it will help people in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
super.onBackPressed()
```

before finish()

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.finish()`  OR

Try   `super.onBackPressed();`         OR

call `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` to get back to previous screen/ activity